# Email verification for Firebase Auth UI

Tags: java, android, firebaseui

I am using `firebase auth UI` ([FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md)) in an android app, where the user can signup with personal `email`, `Facebook`, `number` and `Gmail` accounts. My question is I need to get email verification when user sign's up with his personal email id.

```
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build(),
        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build());

    startActivityForResult(
        AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true)
                .setTheme(R.style.GreenTheme)
                .setTosUrl("https://termsfeed.com/blog/terms-conditions-mobile-apps/")
                .setPrivacyPolicyUrl("https://superapp.example.com/privacy-policy.html")
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .build(),
        RC_SIGN_IN);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // RC_SIGN_IN is the request code you passed into startActivityForResult(...) when starting the sign in flow.
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
        // Successfully signed in
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        } else {
            // Sign in failed
            if (response == null) {
                Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),"Sign in cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                return;
            }

            if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
                Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                return;
            }

            if (response.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
                Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),"Unkown Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                return;
            }
        }
        Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(),"Unknown sign in response",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
    }
}
```

Here is my intent for sign up options.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do it as follows,

1. Get Current Firebase User Instance,

   ```
   final FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
   ```
2. Check if the provider is `password` indicating that the login method used is `Email Auth`,

   ```
   if(null != currentUser) {
       if("password".equals(currentUser.getProviderData().get(0).getProviderId())) {
           /* Handle Verification */
       }
   }
   ```

   **Reference Link**: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/EmailAuthProvider#PROVIDER_ID
3. Check if user is already verified,

   ```
   currentUser.isEmailVerified();
   ```
4. If user is not verified then the following code can be used to send a verification EMail,

   ```
   if (!currentUser.isEmailVerified()) {
       /* Do Something */
   }

   /* Send Verification Email */
   currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
           .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                   /* Check Success */
                   if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                               "Verification Email Sent To: " + currentUser.getEmail(),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   } else {
                       Log.e(TAG, "sendEmailVerification", task.getException());
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                               "Failed To Send Verification Email!",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           });
   ```

Once you have all the pieces in place, the final code snippet should look something like below:

**Final Code Snippet:**

```
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
    IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

    /* Success */
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(null != currentUser) {
            if("password".equals(currentUser.getProviderData().get(0).getProviderId())) {
                if(!currentUser.isEmailVerified()) {
                    /* Send Verification Email */
                    currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                /* Check Success */
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Verification Email Sent To: " + currentUser.getEmail(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "sendEmailVerification", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Failed To Send Verification Email!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    /* Handle Case When Email Not Verified */
                }
            }

            /* Login Success */
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }
    } else {
        /* Handle Failure */
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u please tell me where exactly the code goes into my code?

Comment: @ravi Once you login i.e. `resultCode == RESULT_OK` you'll first have to check the `Provider Id` for the `currentUser`. If the `Provider Id` indicates that the login method is `Email` then you'll check if the user is already verified. If not, you can send out an email using the above code snippet and display a toast indicating that the account needs verification.

Comment: currentUser.getProviderData().get(0).getProviderId() return 'firebase'

Answer (score 1):

@user2004685 answer above gives very good hint. But it does not work at least for the latest firebase-ui because `currentUser.getProviderData().get(0).getProviderId()` returns 'firebase'.

So the updated solution is

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
    IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

    /* Success */
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(null != currentUser) {
            if(currentUser.getEmail()!=null) {
                if(!currentUser.isEmailVerified()) {
                    /* Send Verification Email */
                    currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                /* Check Success */
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Verification Email Sent To: " + currentUser.getEmail(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "sendEmailVerification", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Failed To Send Verification Email!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    /* Handle Case When Email Not Verified */
                }
            }

            /* Login Success */
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }
    } else {
        /* Handle Failure */
    }
  }
}
```

simply replace `if("password".equals(currentUser.getProviderData().get(0).getProviderId()))` with `if(currentUser.getEmail()!=null)`